# How to mock static method of API

Tags: java, api, testing, junit

Hi here is my method to test:

```
public String getRequestBuilder(String foo1) {
    RequestBuilder RequestBuilder = ClientRequest.authorizationProvider(AuthProviderType.footype);
    String locationURI = someclassmethod.getLocationURI(RequestBuilder, foo, foo1);
    return locationURI;
}
```

Here is my test case:

```
@Test
public void test_foo() {
    when(someotherclass.getLocationURI(Matchers.eq(mockRequestBuilder), Matchers.eq("foo"),
    Matchers.eq("foo1"))).thenReturn("locationURI");
    assertEquals("locationURI", Properties.getRequestBuilder("foo1"));
}
```

In the method

```
RequestBuilder RequestBuilder = ClientRequest.authorizationProvider(AuthProviderType.foo);
```

is a static method provided by API. I do not want to use PowerMockito for this. If I use

```
Matchers.any()
```

in place of

```
Matchers.eq(mockRequestBuilder)
```

the test case passes. But using Matchers.any wouldn't provide me the exact value. Is there any way to work into this test case? Foo is the value we retreive from another class method.

Comment: Does this API have any way to configure what exactly is returned by `authorizationProvider`? A configuration property or a dependency injection mechanism perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still check the passed value using [ArgumentCaptor](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html).

```
@Test
public void test_foo() {
    ArgumentCaptor<RequestBuilder> reqCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(RequestBuilder.class);
    when(someotherclass.getLocationURI(any(RequestBuilder.class), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn("locationURI");
    assertEquals("locationURI", Properties.getRequestBuilder("foo1"));
    verify(someotherclass).getLocationURI(reqCaptor.capture(), "foo1", "foo2");
    //Here you can check that reqCaptor.getValue() is equals to expected RequestBuilder and fail the test if not.
}
```

In this case you don't need to use PowerMock to mock static method.

Comment: while checking the actual value for RequestBuilder argumentCaptor, Shall I call: someotherclass.getLocationURI(Matchers.any(RequestBuilder.class), Matchers.eq("foo"),
    Matchers.eq("foo1"));? passing the value for Matchers.any(RequestBuilder.class)

Comment: I suppose you want to test `getRequestBuilder()` method. So, `getLocationURI` must be called inside of `getRequestBuilder`. No need to explicit call of `getLocationURI`.

Comment: But RequestBuilder is built using static method and then sent as a parameter to getLocationURI method.

Comment: Yes, but you cannot mock static methods using `Mockito`. So if it's vital for test to mock it and you don't want to use `PowerMock` i will suggest to refactor your method to make it more testable. Whatever you can just use `Matchers.any()` in your test and then using `ArgumentCaptor` to check value that has been passed to `getLocationURI`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the ArgumentCaptor, you can also introduce a factory that creates a RequestBuilder object for you.

Then you can mock that factory; and more importantly: the fact that you need to call some static method on some other class ... is hidden in that factory; and doesn't cause trouble for other parts of your code.